# Replacing an icon with text in a button CSS

Tags: html, css, button

In a button I have, I need to replace a cart icon so instead of the icon the button say "Add to cart"

What I'm doing is:
content: "Add to cart" ;

And it kind of works but how can edit this to have spaces between the Addtocart?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please take the [tour] and then come back and [edit] the question to add the necessary improvements - for starters, a [mcve] of what you have so far would really help

Answer (score 0):

This sounds quite simple? Maybe we need a better example but to put text in a button it's as simple as:

```
<button>
 add to cart
</button>
```

Unless I'm missing something about your question that's it. Try also adding margin or padding with css if that helps.

Comment: Sorry I may not be clear, I have a button that first says "Add to cart" when I hover over the button it changes and display a cart icon, what I want is to display also the "add to cart" text when hoovering instead of the cart icon, so that's why i'm trying to do it with content:"add to cart" any help you can give me I appreciate it!

Comment: why not remove the CSS that switches the content of the button to the icon? that way it starts with text and on 'hover' it does not get deleted... seems simpler

Comment: Try looking in your css for a class relating to your button. Then look for the psuedo element :hover

from there just delete the code in there or change it. Try looking at the css content property.